# How to debug prestashop using Aptana?

Tags: php, aptana, prestashop

I just downloaded and installed [Prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com), which is a PHP e-commerce system.
I also downloaded and installed XAMPP and [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com) , an open source IDE for PHP development. It uses MVC of some sort. (Sorry, I am completely new to PHP).
It looks ok, I can access the site and the changes I perform in Aptana are reflected in my localhost website.
Now I would like to debug the execution, Aptana has an built-in debugger and it works for a test example I downloaded from the internet ([here](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/suggestions/266-aptana-studio-debugger-for-firefox-36firebug-16)). It works.
But when I try to set the breakpoint in the Prestashop project, it does not suspend the execution. Also, when I click on a link, the debugger stops.

I really have no idea how to set it up. Do you  have any experience in debugging PHP? How can I set it up? I would be fine to change the IDE, if it helped me debugging this system.

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prestashop has some good debug code built in already.

In `config/config.inc.php` change the define for `_PS_DEBUG_SQL_` to true (you can also turn error reporting on in here) and in `config/defines.inc.php` set the define for `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to true also.

Answer (score -1):

Use Netbeans to debug your prestashop. In Netbeans you can use Unit Test or etc. check [Netbeans tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html) for detail